# Git - How to prevent merge or pull from master branch to a particular branch?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket and I have the below branching model;

[image: Branching model]

In this diagram, orange arrows indicate merge to master branch from develop branches. Green lines indicates merges from master to develop / release branches. Changes in lower version develop branches will go to higher version develop branches, through master branch.

Changes from the lower branches will get propagated automatically to higher branches using [**automerge** feature of Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html). When a commit happens in V1, it will be merged to master. From master, it will go to V2 and V3. If commit happens in V2, it will be merged to master and from there, it will be merged to V3, and it will not get merged to V1. This is what happens with `automerge` feature.

This looks fine. But my question is, is it possible to prevent merge `Master -> V1` if the commits in that merge are related `V2`. Normal merge from V2 to V1, v3 to v1, and V2 to V1 should be restricted. In short, merge should not happen from higher to lower versions. Is this possible?